# Showing touch keyboard on custom control

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

The [Touch keyboard sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/93bdfb92b3da76f2e49c959807fc5643bf0940c9/Samples/TouchKeyboard) shows a way for developers to inform the system to display touch keyboard as user touch a custom control [probably in tablet mode]. It was remarked that

> On the PC, you can request that the touch keyboard display for a custom control by implementing the TextPattern provider interface (ITextProvider) and the ValuePattern provider interface (IValueProvider). **Not supported on Phone.**

Does anyone know how to achieve the same thing on Windows 10 phones? As a side note, I wonder why there is such a disparity between desktop and phone. I thought Continuum works in any scenario.

Answer (score 2):

On phone you I think you should be able to do use [InputPane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx) and [CoreWindow.CharacterReceived event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx). Subscribe to the event to know what key has been clicked and show/hide keyboard with *InputPane's* methods. A sample showing keystrokes can look like this:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Character received -> {e.KeyCode}");
        e.Handled = true;
    };
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InputPane pane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
    pane.TryShow();
}
```